# HTTP 302 "Moved Temporarily" Error

Tags: tfs, http-status-code-302

While we are getting latest project from TFS2013, we are facing below error.

[image]

PS: We are using proxy in our network.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you able to get latest before? Did you try on another client machine?

Comment: we tried to another machine from outside environment and its worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced with the same problem before and when I add my ip adress to proxy then try again to do Get latest in TFS. Its worked!!!. Have a nice coding :)